# Canonical question: "is it safe to post ____ online?"

Tags: discussion

There have been quite a few questions in recent history in which people ask if it is safe to post the following things in publicly available places:

[Full Name](https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=name%20online), [Date of Birth](https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=date%20of%20birth), Address, Email, [Phone Number](https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=phone%20number), [IP](https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=ip%20safe), Credit Card, [SSN](https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=ssn%20safe) ...

Does a canonical q/a exist for this already?

Should there be one?

Could it exist without being highly opinionated?

Comment: Wouldn't a canonical question just result in "use your common sense" answers and neglect that there are differences? I find the per-category answers (e.g. for your [full name](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/46569/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-your-real-name-online) or your [date of birth](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/95029/how-dangerous-is-it-to-reveal-your-date-of-birth-and-why)) pretty useful.

Comment: well the answer to most questions could be "use common sense" ... problem is that it is not so common.  Multiple different questions does make sense but I didnt know which ones where out there already.

Comment: Are you suggesting one question for all types of personal information, e.g. "What kind of personal information can I post online?" That sounds to broad to me.